# Neural Network can't learn XOR

Tags: neural-network, xor, backpropagation

I've created a neural network, with the following structure:

Input1 - Input2 - Input layer.

N0 - N1 - Hidden layer. 3 Weights per node (one for bias).

N2 - Output layer. 3 Weights (one for bias).

I am trying to train it the XOR function with the following test data:

- 0 1 - desired result: 1
- 1 0 - desired result: 1
- 0 0 - desired result: 0
- 1 1 - desired result: 0

After training, the mean square error of test (when looking for a 1 result) {0, 1} = **0**, which is good I presume. However the mean square error of test (when looking for a 0 result) {1, 1} = **0.5**, which surely needs to be zero. During the learn stage I notice the MSE of true results drops to zero within the first few epochs, whereas MSE of false results lingers around 0.5.

I'm using back propagation to train the network, with a sigmoid function. The issue is that when I test any combination after the training, I always get a **1.0 result** ouput. - The network seems to learn very fast, even with an extremely small learning rate.

If it helps, here is the weights that are produced:

N0-W0 = **0.5**, N0-W1 = **-0.999**, N0-W2 = **0.304** (bias) - Hidden Layer

N1-W0 = **0.674**, N1-W1 = **-0.893**, N1-W2 = **0.516** (bias) - Hidden Layer

N2-W0 = **-0.243**, N2-W1 = **0.955**, N3-W2 = **0.369** (bias) - Output node

Thanks.

Comment: Thought exercise for you: you have 3x2 + 3 = 9 weights in the network (if I understood correctly). Think of them as 9 unknowns you are solving for. And think of your 4 training inputs as 4 equations that you can use to solve for the unknowns. Now, does it make sense to solve a system of 4 equations that has 9 unknowns? What happens when you try to do that?

Comment: If you are using a sigmoid function, let the weights go above 1 and beyond -1 so that the result of the sigmoid function can be more precise.

Some of my NN needed weights that are very high (several hundreds) or very low in order to perform well.

Answer (score 0):

These are some steps which can help solve your problem:

1. Change your activation function. Here is a similar question which I answered using relu as the activation function: [Neural network XOR gate not learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561182/neural-network-xor-gate-not-learning/38767930#38767930)
2. Increase the the number of epochs.
3. Change your learning rate to a larger suitable value, so that you can reach convergence faster. You can find more info here:
   [How to determine the learning rate and the variance in a gradient descent algorithm？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640470/how-to-determine-the-learning-rate-and-the-variance-in-a-gradient-descent-algori)